# How i change the header of audio ogg files in php

Tags: php, audio, concatenation, audio-recording, ogg

I have concatenate two different audio ogg files. But the length of output file is same as the first files. 
For Ex. I have two files

1. a.ogg with 
   Title - abc and
   length - 0.20 min
2. b.ogg with 
   Title - efg and 
   length - 1.20 min

When I join the these two files it is working fine but the length is showing 0.20 min in player. 
How can I change the length and headers in "Core PHP"?

Here is the code

```
$fp = fopen('sounds/a.ogg', 'r');
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
$audio1 ='';
while ($audio_data = fread($fp, 8192)) {
    $audio1 .=$audio_data;
}
fclose($fp);

$fp = fopen('sounds/example.ogg', 'r');

/* Collect some information about the file. */
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

$audio2 ='';
while ($audio_data = fread($fp, 8192)) {
    $audio2 .=$audio_data;
}
fclose($fp);
$a3 = $audio1 . $audio2;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg-3');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testing.ogg"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($a3));
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $a3;
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code where you concatenate the files with?

Comment: Hi Norbert van Nobelen, I have edit the post with my code

Comment: The basic premise is ok. The problem is in not having chapters in your ogg file (which is technically possible, but no samples found so far). Upvoted the question for more attention.

Comment: http://demos.cybershines.com/concatOgg/oggConcat.php here you can see the output.